# What governs the actions of the Enterprise's doors?

Tags: star-trek, technology

Is there any in-universe logic to how the Enterprise's doors behave?

Out-of-universe, they open/close if and only if the plot demands it, but in-universe they can close (`glad to be of service!`) with someone standing directly in front of them: in the Netflix version of TNG S4E2 ("Family"), timestamp 1min34 remaining, the doors shut while Picard is still looking directly through them. In the following picture, the doors are closing after Worf's parents have just gone through them and Picard has elected not to.

[image: TNG S4E2, doors closing]

Is there an in-universe explanation for why the doors shut then, rather than remaining open for Picard?

([This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99483/what-if-any-locking-mechanism-do-the-doors-have-on-the-enterprise) is similar but not quite the same.)

Comment: A few years ago the producers of Stargate were asked "*what determines when the Stargate closes?*". Their answer was that "*the Stargate checks the script, and if the script says 'Stargate Closes' then that's what it does*". I suspect the mechanism on these doors is very similar.

Comment: The lads operating the doors close it on queue (or if feeling emboldened, as an actor is about to walk through)

Comment: @Valorum I tried answering a question on that very thing on this very site with that very answer. Did not go over well. ;)

Comment: @WillihamTotland - It depends. In this case (and probably that case) the OP is looking for an in-universe answer.

Comment: @Valorum Sure, but sometimes there isn't one.

Comment: I won't be too surprised if there isn't an in-universe answer, but I wouldn't be at all surprised either if there were one; since people are dedicated enough to learn Klingon, perhaps they are also dedicated enough to work out how the doors work.

Comment: @WillihamTotland - You always have to remember that the Enteprise' systems are controlled by a powerful Turing-capable AI. Whenever you ask yourself "***how did the Enterprise know to do that?***", you can *always* attribute it to the ship's computer.

Comment: "What governs the actions of the Enterprise's doors?" The doors open when you make the **shwoosht** sound.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The Computer Sees All**

As Valorum points out in the comments, the ship's computer is an advanced ([but intentionally gimped](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73365/the-moriarty-sentience-problem-a-k-a-why-isnt-the-enterprise-computer-consid/73423#73423)) AI system. The computer [constantly monitors the whereabouts and disposition of all ship inhabitants.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34992/why-dont-starfleet-ships-transport-injured-crew-members-to-sick-bay-automatical) It [doesn't always make the best use of this ability](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/2zpzic/apparently_people_go_missing_from_starships_all/), but is apparently very effective at operating automatic doors.

**The computer uses the same reasoning that you as a human have in determining that Picard is "done" in the room and not about to walk back in**. Rather than "in-universe logic", it is likely based on [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) having built associations between complex behaviors and door opening.
This doesn't require much more advanced technology than exists today. It could be that doors "default" to a closed state, and only open when the computer sees someone attempting to walk into them.

By the 24th century it's considered so commonplace and simple that nobody has ever felt it necessary to explain how it works in-universe. It is a technology taken for granted. (except when it [doesn't work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMX9ZAD_h3g))